# Is it possible to retrieve the value entry for a specific String ID in a String Table?

Tags: visual-c++, resources

I'm new to using the String Table in a Resource File(.rc) in VC6. I can see that the String Table contains three columns: ID, Value and Caption. I know that I use CString.LoadString() to retrieve the Caption given the ID. However, is a way to retrieve the Value when you have the ID?

If so, can I also then retrieve the Caption using a Value?

Thanks!

Comment: So I am a C++ noob. I was told that "the ID is just a #define for the Value, so they are the same thing. Look at your resource.h file." Problem fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am a C++ noob. I was told that "the ID is just a #define for the Value, so they are the same thing. Look at your resource.h file." Problem fixed!

Comment: Being new to C++ and being asked to use a 15 year old version of a compiler is a horrible combination.  Your first job is very, very important, it is a very strong predictor for what you'll do the next 10 years.  That place is where hope goes to die, in spite of everything you don't know yet, it got stuck in a rut a long time ago.  Keep looking.

Comment: That's kind of depressing. I don't think I will be working with C++ and VC6 forever. We will eventually move to the web with C#.